# android Record a RTSP stream in a file from SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rtsp

I'm showing a RTPS live stream (from a camera) into a SurfaceView (my_surface_view) using camera's IP. 
For this i'm using the follow library -> implementation '**com.github.pedroSG94.vlc-example-streamplayer:libvlc:2.5.14v3**'

I need to implement a feature so the user can record the stream into a File but when i try to record my video from my surface view using mediaRecorder i get : **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a PersistentSurface**

Here is my code :

```
    mediaRecorder.setInputSurface(my_surface_view.holder.hurface)
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT)
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000)
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480)
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(File(getVideosDirectory(), "TEST.mp4").path)
    mediaRecorder.prepare()
    mediaRecorder.start()
```

I ve look on the internet but i didn t found any library or example. And right now i'm stuck and have no ideea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to do it using FFmpeg ->

`implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'`

For starting the recording (make sure it s not on main thread), and the file have the .mkv extension

```
   runOnIoThread {
                FFmpeg.execute("-i $url -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy ${file.path}")
            }
```

and to stop it -> `FFmpeg.cancel()`

Comment: Hello, I am stuck in the same issue. I successfully played rtsp video via vlc streamplayer sdk but cannot record the video. What was your solution? Could you provide me an example code?

Comment: Please provide any update for this solution,Thanks